# CrossSlide plugin for image change error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying set up my website to change banner image over time. I have found the CrossSlide jQuery plugin. It seems pretty easy to use, but it is nor working.

Anyways here is my code:

HTML

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sk" lang="sk">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>TITLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/main.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cross-slide.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#ban').crossSlide({
    sleep: 2,
    fade: 1
    }, [
  { src: 'img/nehn1.png' },
  { src: 'img/nehn2.png'   },
  { src: 'img/nehn3.png'  },
  { src: 'img/nehn4.png' }
  ]);

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
...
<div id="banner"></div>
...
```

CSS for banner div:

```
#banner{
height:417px;
width:100%;
background:url('../img/banner.png')no-repeat;
background-position:top center; 
padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

I have tried to put there  tag, instead to load my image as divs background and nothing happened. I have also tried to set the width to 1920px and also nothing.
In console I am getting this errors:

This error is related to the plugin file it self (exactly line 6)
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

And here is second error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'crossSlide'   test542014.html:12
 (anonymous function) test542014.html:12
 c jquery.js:7341
 p.fireWith jquery.js:7403
 b.extend.ready jquery.js:6875
 H jquery.js:6601
```

Can anyone suggest some solution to this, or maybe another plugin, that is tested and can do this work right?

Thank you

Comment: Is this the plugin you're using https://github.com/tobia/CrossSlide? If so I'd recommend using a more up to date solution

Comment: @moo2u2 Yes, it is exactly that plugin. And can you please suggest something else, that is more up to date? Thx

Comment: Not sure what specific requirements you have but check out http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/, it's lightweight, responsive, and has swipe events for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you include jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

this should help you.